# How to prevent jquery UI slider from skipping slide values?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array, where each index causes an action to  be performed in a buildup.
When I slide the slider, I notice that when I do: ui.value, it sometimes "skips" numbers. For example... the slider may start 0,1,2,3,4, but if I slide a little faster, it may jump from 54 to 56, in which since 55 is skipped, I miss an actioin that is performed there.

How can I make sure that if the user "slides the mouse a little fast", it will make sure the slide event is fired for each of the numbers with step size of 1? or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

You can actually make a very easy work around by keeping the old value. If your old value is 53 and now its 56, then fire events for 54, 55 and then perform the event for 56

Comment: @Rolando well unless the user slides forwards and then backwards super quickly then it shouldn't be a problem. But if your program can't afford that happening then yea this won't work

Comment: Hence looking for the best solution to this issue.